# export excel columns into multiple text files

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

I need to split data [1...M]  gathered in columns [A...N] into separate text files named as first cell of each column.

Data arranged in excel:

```
FileName_A  |FileName_B |FileName_C |…      |FileName_N
Data_A1     |Data_B1        |Data_C1        |…      |Data_N1
Data_A2     |Data_B2        |Data_C2        |…      |Data_N2
Data_A3     |Data_B3        |Data_C3        |…      |Data_N3
…       …       …       …       …
DataA_AM    DataA_BM    DataA_CM    DataA_AM    DataA_NM
____________________________________________________________________________
```

shall be written into FileNames

FileName_A.tex should look like:

```
_____________
Data_A1
Data_A2
Data_A3
…
DataA_AM
____________
```

I´ve tried, but...

Altough it seems an easy task for an expert, it is quite a huge obsticle for me becouse I am not familiar with coding.

Thank You very much for support in advance.

Comment: You've tried what exactly? Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54149532/edit) to let us know?

Comment: What is "M" ? The number of rows ? How many is that ? Do you want to manually enter them ?

Comment: I have measureing points in different columns [from 1 to N]. Labels ar written in first row.
Below I have measuring data [row 2 to M] of each measuring point.

I have to put measurements of each measuring point into single file.

I want to label text file from measuring point A [cell A1] with FileName_A.tex, which includes data from [cell A2] to [cell A34]
and
[cell B1] FileName_B.tex with data from [cell B2] to [cell B34]
...

Comment: M is the number of rows between 10 to 50.
They are entered manually, but i get files 3 times a day for additional editing.

Comment: You need to rewrite the question to ask the following: 1. Is it possible to export columns of data into text files? 2. If it is possible what method should I use, whether it be excel functionality or special coding functionality.  

I am certain you can do this based on excel functionality... no coding needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Code below.

```
    Sub export_data()
    Dim row, column, i, j As Integer
    Dim fullPath, myFile As String

    fullPath = "C:\Workspace"
    row = 21
    column = 5

    For i = 1 To column
        myFile = Cells(1, i).Value + ".txt"
        myFile = fullPath + "/" + myFile
        Open myFile For Output As #1
        For j = 2 To row
            Print #1, Cells(j, i).Value
        Next j
        Close #1
    Next i

    End Sub
```

You can change Row number and Column number. Your First row is always Header. 
See Image below for Excel

[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDObt.png)

Comment: JUGAL SHAH, You are genius.

The code is clear and simple for illiterate.

Thank You whereever you are.

Answer (score 1):

So, I assumed that M is an Integer Variable that you already defined and N just the Column Name (So column number 14). The code would then be

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer

For i = 1 To 14

Range(Cells("2", i), Cells(M, i)).ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypeXPS, _
    Filename:=Sheets(1).Cells("1", i), _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next
```

You might want to replace `Filename:=Sheets(1).Cells("1", i), _` with `Filename:="C:/Your_Path/ & Sheets(1).Cells("1", i), _`

Comment: Thank You Thryn.

It is my /if I can say so/ first VBA code.
I will do my best.
Have a nice day.

Comment: We've all been there, don't worry :) If that answered your problem, don't forget to check the tick to mark the question as answered. If not, I might help you solve why.

Comment: It does not work. Don´t know why.
All data are strings, not numbers.

I have 14 columns. First cell in row is FileName. Other cells are string data.